# Display the information of xlsx file or csv file from Azure Blob Storage to Power apps

Tags: azure, csv, azure-blob-storage, xlsx, powerapps

I am trying to use a xlsx or csv file from my Azure Blob Storage as my data source in my powerapps and display the information in a gallery in powerapps. With the Blob Storage connector I am given two methods 'GetFileContentV2'  and 'GetFileContentByPathV2'. But I don't know how to enter the parameters to get the information from my file. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can you give some more info on what you have actually tried already?

Comment: Please edit to provide specifics. As written, there's no code, no error, no other details, so there's really no way to help.